# R: ORA - 01805 error while connecting to oracle database using R

Tags: r, oracle, oracle11g

I am connecting to Oracle database server using R. While i try to fetch the data, I am getting error as

```
Error in .oci.fetch(res, as.integer(n)) : 
  ORA-01805: possible error in date/time operation
```

I dont have oracle skill set, however i connect to the database only for fetching the data.

If you need any other information, I am ready to provide.

Also if you think that i posted this question in an in appropriate tag, kindly point me the right tag. Thank you in advance.

** EDIT **
Posting some more information:

This is the code and table details(masked) that i use to connect oracle from R

```
drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
host <- "xyzdbqa"
port <- nnnnn
sid <- "abc1"

connect.string <- paste(
  "(DESCRIPTION=",
  "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", port, "))",
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=", sid, ")))", sep = "")


con <- dbConnect(drv, username = "xyz",password = "xyz1",dbname=connect.string)


query.string <- paste ( "SELECT * FROM data_base_Table WHERE VALUE_DATE='10-dec-2015'",                 
                        sep = "")

print('Connection Established')

rs_testdata <- dbSendQuery(con,query.string)

print('Query Sent')

test_data <- fetch(rs_testdata)
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I have provided some more information. Please let me know if this is ok.

Comment: Here are the details, it is due to timezone mismatch between the client (R in this case) and Oracle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678485/oracle-ora-01805-on-oracle-11g-database

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju - Could you please let me know how should i check for the timezone mismatch? I am able to connect to the one another table from the same database.